# 1600x900 or 1920x1080 over DVI on Mac using Quadro 410

Tags: mac, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, dvi, macos-sierra

a couple of years ago I built myself a Franken-Mac using some hardware from iMacs and a few Mac compatible parts, namely I needed hyper-threading so it uses an i3-4330 rather than an i5-2500, and I needed business level graphics but couldn't afford the horrifyingly expensive Quadro 4000 for Mac, (yes I know $500 isn't that expensive relative to other GCs especially other Quadros however the most I am willing to pay for a piece of graphics hardware is about $150, especially seeing as my CPU already has an integrated GPU with as much VRAM and only barely less support for OpenGL/Shaders). So I ended up using the Quadro 410 and a graphics injection driver to save money.

Now the above was just to give context as to how and why I am using a Quadro 410 and IHD4600 on a Mac, the actual question is if there is a way to run the graphics at either 1600x900 or 1920x1080 over the DVI connection on said Quadro 410 on a Mac. Seeing as DVI supports well over 1080p, the Quadro 410 has support for up to 3K, and macOS 10.12 obviously supports up to 5K it is confusing to me that the highest resolution I am able to select in Settings>Display is 1360x768. Not to mention there was a period where I was gaming less and used the IHD4600 graphics via HDMI and it supported both 1600x900 and 1920x1080 in Settings, it even had an option for 2560x1440! (The maxmimum resolution that the IHD4600 GPU supports.)

So why is it that using a driver that supports up to 1920x1080, on a GPU that supports up to 3K, over a connection that supports up to 2K running on an OS that supports up to 5K the highest resolution I am able to achieve is 1360x768? It doesn't make any sense to me. (BTW I know for a fact it isn't a problem with using the injected graphics driver, because I have an installation of Windows 7 on my second HDD on the Franken-Mac that also has a resolution cap of 1360x768 in Control Panel>Change Resolution, and was likewise able to select up to 1920x1080 with the IHD4600) D:

Comment: What kind of monitor is plugged in?

Comment: A 1080p T.V. with upscaling support for 2K, which I should mention is also the same T.V. that the IHD4600 was connected to via HDMI when I was given the option to use 2K

Comment: You realise that in terms of 'gaming performance' your on-chip Intel 4600 is about twice as fast as the Quadro? Quadros are just not built for gaming & perform poorly. Your self-imposed 150 bucks spend could these days buy an NVidia 10150Ti, which would run rings round the quadro; alternatively a Mac-flashed AMD R9 280X, slightly more expensive but you'll be able to see the boot screen unlike with a modern NVidia.

Comment: @Testujin, this is not a question about which graphics card I should use, it is not about resolution in game. It is also not about game preformance, and while Quadro cards are not built specifically for gaming it is a myth that they perform poorly. Not to mention that you claim the IHD4600 is twice as fast when gaming, but when you account for it's lesser Shader, OpenGL, and DirectX support, on top of the fact that most games are not designed for or compatible with the IHD4600 you end up with less games that start and most performing worse. This is about in-OS resolution. Please stay on topic.